# wso2 Securing Passwords in Configuration Files

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have downloaded wso2 api manager wso2am-2.1.0 and working on encrypting password for configuration files.

I have followed steps to encrypt password in configuration files .
but after following these steps if i start my wos2 server with wso2server.bat file , it is asking password. i have given password i.e; wso2carbon.
i am getting below error :

```
[2017-05-15 16:43:46,666] FATAL - TomcatBundleActivator Error while starting server NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.AttributeMap.internalRemoveNamedItem(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.AttributeMap.removeNamedItem(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager.init(ServerManager.java:106)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.TomcatBundleActivator.start(TomcatBundleActivator.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
[2017-05-15 16:43:51,336]  INFO - BinaryDataReceiver Started Binary SSL Transport on port : 9711
[2017-05-15 16:43:51,338]  INFO - BinaryDataReceiver Started Binary TCP Transport on port : 9611
[2017-05-15 16:43:51,351]  INFO - DataBridgeDS Successfully deployed Agent Server
[2017-05-15 16:43:51,610]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Configured Registry in 66ms
[2017-05-15 16:43:51,746]  INFO - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2017-05-15 16:43:51,837]  INFO - AndesConfigurationManager Main andes configuration located at : C:\wso2\WSO2AM~2.0\bin\../repository/conf/broker.xml
[2017-05-15 16:43:52,067]  INFO - AndesConfigurationManager Main andes configuration located at : C:\wso2\WSO2AM~2.0\bin\../repository/conf/broker.xml
[2017-05-15 16:44:00,158]  INFO - JDBCReporterBuilder Creating JDBC reporter for Metrics with source 'BLR-LP249SPGX', data source 'jdbc/WSO2MetricsDB' and 60 seconds polling period
[2017-05-15 16:44:00,162]  INFO - JmxReporterBuilder Creating JMX reporter for Metrics with domain 'org.wso2.carbon.metrics'
[2017-05-15 16:44:00,185]  INFO - AbstractReporter Started JDBC reporter for Metrics
[2017-05-15 16:44:00,186]  INFO - AbstractReporter Started JMX reporter for Metrics
[2017-05-15 16:44:05,174]  INFO - SolrClient Default Embedded Solr Server Initialized
[2017-05-15 16:44:05,734]  INFO - UserStoreMgtDSComponent Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
```

can someone help me.

Comment: Did you follow any documentation to securing the password? What did you change (carbon.xml, catalina-server.xml , ... )? Are you sure the XML's are valid (XML encoding the values)   Maybe duplicate of this issue https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-15380 ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with the base 2.1.0 release that is available for download.  This issue is corrected through a WUM updated pack.  If you do not have a Production subscription I am not sure what steps you would take to resolve.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-16104

Comment: I am facing problem after encryption i restarted my wso2 server .
i am not able to generate Access token for application 
This is the error i am getting :
"Error while renewing Access Token for Consumer Key gjo5e4Nn9ncsBzvNex31jaRsnvUa and user admin
"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like issue https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-15380, according to the post you need to encrypt the keystore password in the catalina-server.xml as well

Comment: catalina-server.xml entry was already there in place in cipher-tool.properties file as below :
Server.Service.Connector.keystorePass=repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml//Server/Service/Connector[@keystorePass],true