# getting exception after encrypting password of conf/axis2/axsi2.xml

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

getting exception after encrypting password of conf/axis2/axsi2.xml , i have used ciphertool.sh to encrypt the password.
i was able to encrypt the other files of /repository/conf dir .

Did anyone faced same issue.
Thanks you.

Comment: What Version?  What was the exception?  You may want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978489/wso2-securing-passwords-in-configuration-files/43980912#43980912

Comment: Version : wso2am-2.1.0 and on top of that i have taken WUM update last week.other files i was able to encrypt , i am facing problem only after encrypting password for axis2.xml

Answer (score 0):

**we have seen problem to Encrypt axis2.xml .But after using below aliases and x-path we were able to encrypt passwords for axis2.xml:**
Axis2.Https.Listener.TrustStore.Password=repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml//axisconfig/transportReceiver[@name='https']/parameter[@name='truststore']/TrustStore/Password,false

Axis2.Https.Listener.KeyStore.Password=repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml//axisconfig/transportReceiver[@name='https']/parameter[@name='keystore']/KeyStore/Password,false

Axis2.Https.Listener.KeyStore.KeyPassword=repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml//axisconfig/transportReceiver[@name='https']/parameter[@name='keystore']/KeyStore/KeyPassword,false

Axis2.Https.Sender.TrustStore.Password=repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml//axisconfig/transportSender[@name='https']/parameter[@name='truststore']/TrustStore/Password,false

Axis2.Https.Sender.KeyStore.Password=repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml//axisconfig/transportSender[@name='https']/parameter[@name='keystore']/KeyStore/Password,false

Axis2.Https.Sender.KeyStore.KeyPassword=repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml//axisconfig/transportSender[@name='https']/parameter[@name='keystore']/KeyStore/KeyPassword,false